# MeshLab Quadric Edge Collapse Decimation preserving textures in JavaScript, PHP or Python?

Tags: javascript, php, python, mesh, meshlab

There is a filter in MeshLab that I normally use to decimate (or simplify) 3D models that were 'photogrammetised'; to  a lower number of faces (so that they can be viewed faster on mobile client devices). The filter used is the Quadric Edge Collapse Decimation preserving textures.

I want to do this in **bulk and programmatically** from the web server side; so that those decimations (or simplifications) are done in batch and then stored in backend system  like Omeka, a digital asset management system, or any other similar system really. I am using currently Sketchfab to view the Web3D models (each has an .obj, mtl and bunch of texture images). Any WebGL library like Three JS or Babylon JS can be used.

The important thing here is that I am looking for any implementation of the MeshLab Quadric Edge Collapse Decimation algorithm **for the web**, ideally either in JavaScript (node), PHP or Python? Any libraries that make the batch decimation or simplification easy?

Thank you for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

**2021 update**

now there is [pymeshlab](https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which allows automatization of meshlab processing through python!

Answer (score 0):

You could try [MLX](https://github.com/3DLIRIOUS/MeshLabXML), my Python frontend to meshlabserver. The Quadric Edge Collapse Decimation filter is implemented as mlx.remesh.simplify.

Comment: Thx a lot. This is an elegant simple tool on GitHub that uses this & simplify the task https://github.com/HusseinBakri/3DMeshBulkSimplification

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways of solving this issue, if you are using Python.

1. You can use [quad-mesh-simplify](https://pypi.org/project/quad-mesh-simplify/). A lightweight package specifically for **simplifying meshes with node features**. The algorithm from [Surface Simplification Using Quadric Error Metrics](http://mgarland.org/files/papers/quadrics.pdf) was implemented using cython.
2. You can also at the popular Open3D (as of v0.9.0.0) function - [simplify_quadric_decimation](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.9.0/python_api/open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.html?highlight=simplify_quadric_decimation#open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.simplify_quadric_decimation)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  Simplify Quadric decimation is a good tool. I am using an elegant & simple tool on GitHub that uses MeshlabXML  Library & simplify the task greatly:  https://github.com/HusseinBakri/3DMeshBulkSimplification